# android studio: android sdk symbol unresolved, but androidTest OK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

androidTest: pass tests using emulator with API level 26

if running from android studio, calling the same code with the same emulator, error occurs.

From debugging, java.util.regex.Pattern

```
private void compile() throws PatternSyntaxException {
    if (pattern == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("pattern == null");
    }

    String icuPattern = pattern;
    if ((flags & LITERAL) != 0) {
        icuPattern = quote(pattern);
    }

    // These are the flags natively supported by ICU.
    // They even have the same value in native code.
    int icuFlags = flags & (CASE_INSENSITIVE | COMMENTS | MULTILINE | DOTALL | UNIX_LINES);
    address = compileImpl(icuPattern, icuFlags);
    registry.registerNativeAllocation(this, address);   <<-------this line error
}
```

Android studio editor showing error when mouse over the line:

```
     registerNativeAllocation can not be resolved.
```

Why androidTest does not have this issue. Is this a lib compatibility issue?

Comment: Do you have some library in gradle as a test only dependency?

Comment: For andriodTest, it has dependency on android test support lib:   com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0, 
com.android.support.test:runner:0.5, 
com.android.support.test:rules:0.5, and junit. When running from android studio, it is not a test. Code is called from MainActivity.

Comment: Android studio has nothing to do with if its a test or not.  And support annotations looks suspicious to have as a test only dependency.